# vis.js How to display a network in a layout with shortest connection line lengths?

Tags: vis.js

Is there an option that helps us draw a network in a layout that keeps the length of all the connection lines the shortest? The goal of this is to try and avoid overlapping edges as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with physics (docs: https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/physics.html). Namely barnesHut.springLength and barnesHut.springConstant, but options like barnesHut.centralGravity or barnesHut.gravitationalConstant could also help to the edges short.

Comment: Thank you Tomas. As far as I can see on their example page: https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/other/configuration.html those options just change the length of all the edges, but I'm more interested in influencing the algorithm that calculates which node to draw on which position in order for the resulting network to have the minimal length of all the edges (in order to avoid intersection of edges as much as possible). I hope that clarifies my goal a little bit.

Comment: Sadly there is no way to affect the layouting algorithm. You can however implement your own algorithm and position the nodes explicitly.